# problemas con fecth async y await en servirdor

Tags: javascript, hosting, fetch, async-await

```js
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    selectWords();
}, false);

let boxCon = document.querySelector('#boxCon');
let boxPro = document.querySelector('#boxPro');
let boxSer = document.querySelector('#boxSer');
let boxSus = document.querySelector('#boxSus');
let boxVer = document.querySelector('#boxVer');
let boxAdj = document.querySelector('#boxAdj');
let boxPoema = document.querySelector('#boxPoema');

function selectWords(){
    let boton1 = document.querySelectorAll('.botonet4');
    boton1.forEach(function(boton1){
        boton1.addEventListener('click',function(e){
            const getWordsAsync = async () => {
                try {

                    const respPro = await fetch(base_url+'poema/pronombres');
                    const pro = await respPro.json();
                    for(let i = 0; i < pro.length; i++) {
                        let pronombreB = document.createElement('button');
                        let txtPro = document.createTextNode(pro[i].pronombre);
                        pronombreB.classList.add("pro");
                        pronombreB.appendChild(txtPro);
                        boxPro.appendChild(pronombreB);
                    }

                    let pronomc = document.querySelectorAll('.pro');
                    pronomc.forEach(function(pronomc){
                        pronomc.addEventListener('click',function(){
                            //boxPro.removeChild(pronombre);
                            let wordPoem = document.createElement('button');
                            wordPoem.classList.add('wordPoem');
                            let content = document.querySelector('#contenido');
                            let pronom = pronomc.innerHTML;
                            console.log(pronom);
                            content.value += pronom + ' ';
                            wordPoem.innerText = pronom;
                            boxPoema.appendChild(wordPoem);
                            wordPoem.addEventListener('click', function(){
                                boxPoema.removeChild(wordPoem);
                                content.value = content.value.replace(pronom + ' ','');
                            });
                        });
                    });

                    const respSer = await fetch(base_url+'poema/seres');
                    const ser = await respSer.json();
                    for(let i = 0; i < ser.length; i++) {
                        let serB = document.createElement('button');
                        serB.classList.add('ser');
                        let txtSer = document.createTextNode(ser[i].ser);
                        serB.appendChild(txtSer);
                        boxSer.appendChild(serB);    
                    }

                    let serB2 = document.querySelectorAll('.ser');
                    serB2.forEach(function(serB2){
                        serB2.addEventListener('click',function(){
                            boxSer.removeChild(serB2);
                            let wordPoem = document.createElement('button');
                            wordPoem.classList.add('wordPoem');
                            let content = document.querySelector('#contenido');
                            let ser2 = serB2.innerHTML;
                            content.value += ser2 + ' ';
                            wordPoem.innerText = ser2;
                            boxPoema.appendChild(wordPoem);
                            wordPoem.addEventListener('click', function(){
                                boxPoema.removeChild(wordPoem);
                                content.value = content.value.replace(ser2 + ' ','');
                            });
                        });
                    });
                    
                    const respAdj = await fetch(base_url+'poema/adjetivos');
                    const adj = await respAdj.json();
                    for(let i = 0; i < adj.length; i++) {
                        let adjetivo = document.createElement('button');
                        adjetivo.classList.add('adj');
                        let txtAdj = document.createTextNode(adj[i].adjetivo);
                        adjetivo.appendChild(txtAdj);
                        boxAdj.appendChild(adjetivo);
                    }

                    let adjB2 = document.querySelectorAll('.adj');
                    adjB2.forEach(function(adjB2){
                        adjB2.addEventListener('click',function(){
                            boxAdj.removeChild(adjB2);
                            let wordPoem = document.createElement('button');
                            wordPoem.classList.add('wordPoem');
                            let content = document.querySelector('#contenido');
                            let adj2 = adjB2.innerHTML;
                            content.value += adj2 + ' ';
                            wordPoem.innerText = adj2;
                            boxPoema.appendChild(wordPoem);
                            wordPoem.addEventListener('click', function(){
                                boxPoema.removeChild(wordPoem);
                                content.value = content.value.replace(adj2 + ' ','');
                            });
                        });
                    });

                    const respVer = await fetch(base_url+'poema/verbos');
                    const ver = await respVer.json();
                    for(let i = 0; i < ver.length; i++) {
                        let verB = document.createElement('button');
                        verB.classList.add('ver');
                        let txtVer = document.createTextNode(ver[i].verbo);
                        verB.appendChild(txtVer);
                        boxVer.appendChild(verB);
                    }

                    let verB2 = document.querySelectorAll('.ver');
                    verB2.forEach(function(verB2){
                        verB2.addEventListener('click',function(){
                            boxVer.removeChild(verB2);
                            let wordPoem = document.createElement('button');
                            wordPoem.classList.add('wordPoem');
                            let content = document.querySelector('#contenido');
                            let ver2 = verB2.innerHTML;
                            content.value += ver2 + ' ';
                            wordPoem.innerText = ver2;
                            boxPoema.appendChild(wordPoem);
                            wordPoem.addEventListener('click', function(){
                                boxPoema.removeChild(wordPoem);
                                content.value = content.value.replace(ver2 + ' ','');
                            });
                        });
                    });

                    const respCon = await fetch(base_url+'poema/conectores');
                    const con = await respCon.json();
                    for(let i = 0; i < con.length; i++){
                        let conn = document.createElement('button');
                        conn.classList.add('con');
                        let txtCon = document.createTextNode(con[i].conector);
                        conn.appendChild(txtCon);
                        boxCon.appendChild(conn);
                    }
                    
                    let conB2 = document.querySelectorAll('.con');
                    conB2.forEach(function(conB2){
                        conB2.addEventListener('click',function(){
                            boxCon.removeChild(conB2);
                            let wordPoem = document.createElement('button');
                            wordPoem.classList.add('wordPoem');
                            let content = document.querySelector('#contenido');
                            let conec = conB2.innerHTML;
                            content.value += conec + ' ';
                            wordPoem.innerText = conec;
                            boxPoema.appendChild(wordPoem);
                            wordPoem.addEventListener('click', function(){
                                boxPoema.removeChild(wordPoem);
                                content.value = content.value.replace(conec + ' ','');
                            });
                        });
                    });

                    const respSus = await fetch(base_url+'poema/sustantivos')
                    const sus = await respSus.json()
                    for(let i = 0; i < sus.length; i++) {
                        let susB = document.createElement('button');
                        susB.classList.add('sus');
                        let txtSus = document.createTextNode(sus[i].sustantivo);
                        susB.appendChild(txtSus);
                        boxSus.appendChild(susB);
                    }

                    let susB2 = document.querySelectorAll('.sus');
                    susB2.forEach(function(susB2){
                        susB2.addEventListener('click',function(){
                            boxSus.removeChild(susB2);
                            let wordPoem = document.createElement('button');
                            wordPoem.classList.add('wordPoem');
                            let content = document.querySelector('#contenido');
                            let sus2 = susB2.innerHTML;
                            content.value += sus2 + ' ';
                            wordPoem.innerText = sus2;
                            boxPoema.appendChild(wordPoem);
                            wordPoem.addEventListener('click', function(){
                                boxPoema.removeChild(wordPoem);
                                content.value = content.value.replace(sus2 + ' ','');
                            });
                        });
                    });

                }catch(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
            getWordsAsync();
            boton1.style.display = "none";
        });     
        
    });
}
```

Hola ! Tengo este srcipt en un servidor pero me dice que hay error de sintaxis el editor del server me marca en las const getWordsAsyn un warning con (Expected '(' and instead saw '{')... en try (Expected an identifier and instead saw 'try' (a reserved word). Expected ')' to match '{' from line 17 instead saw '{')

en la const respPro (Expected an identifier and instead saw 'const'. Missing semicolon)
Alguien sabe por que pasa esto?

No se ya como solucionarlo primero opte por hacer todo esto con ajax pero era mas de lo mismo aunque ahora se rompre totalmente el codigo... Sera un problema del servidor o el problema es mio? Porque en local corre perfecto pero no se porque en el servidor todo es mas fragil parece

Comment: Esto se ejecuta en el cliente y necesitas dar más información para saber qué está pasando, por ejemplo, ¿a qué te refieres con _el editor del server_? Algunos navegadores (supongo que también editores) no reconocen las funciones flecha, probablemente solo debas cambiar eso.

Comment: Al editor que te da el hosting para editar el codigo o revisarlo... ah eso me refiero porque ese codigo ya esta en hosting pero no se porque pasa eso... en cuanto a la funcion de flecha como seria cambiarla ? O sea cual seria el cambio a realizar>?

Comment: ¿Por qué no subes el archivo por FTP? En cuanto a las funciones flecha, solo debes cambiar `() =>` por `function()`

Comment: Subirlo aca en Stack? Se puede ? Aun no se manejar bien la paltaforma soy medio pasmado

Comment: Me refiero a subir tu archivo actual al servidor por FTP, si ya lo tienes, no veo la necesidad de usar el editor.

Comment: Es que ya esta en linea.. ahi hice lo que me dijiste quedo bien pero aun asi en las const me dice missing semicolon ... pero estan todas cerradas ,,,

Comment: el problema puede ser por la versión de javascript que esta validando el lint de tu editor de hosting, en este caso deberías de declarar como `var` en lugar de `const`.

Comment: Estuve pensando en eso pero voy a esperar a mañana a hablar con el hosting por ese caso! Y si no, ya no se que puedo hacer todo el proyecto no serviria de nada porque encima esta funcion es el pilar del sistema u.u

Comment: Deberías de usar el ftp para cargar tus ficheros a el hosting, o subir en un zip tu sitio y ahí desenziparlo, al final son archivos js, todo ese código viaja y  se ejecuta en el cliente.

Comment: Deberia volver subirlo creo hare el intento

Comment: No pasa nada y el hosting no responde ah, gajes del oficio supongo